# "Крынжалы" - это сани, или лыжи?

Tags: этимология, другое

Есть крынжалы – огромные сани или лыжи. Это прицеп к бульдозеру-тягачу  для перевозки крупногабаритных грузов, таких как срубы, брёвна, стога сена. Интересно узнать о происхождении этого названия, а так же разрешить возникший спор: сани это, либо лыжи? Мой оппонент, утверждает, что лыжи, мотивируя это тем, что его бабушка называет растоптанную обувь «крынжалами».

Answer (score 2):

> а так же разрешить возникший спор: сани это, либо лыжи?

Это не лингвистический вопрос. Если очень надо знать ответ, консультируйтесь у технарей или, может, юристов, но никак не у бабушки. Вернее всего, конечно, сани, ибо к ним можно отнести почти все, что на полозьях и движется под управлением внешней тяги.

А касательно происхождения - тут сложнее.
КРЫНДЖАЛЫ или крыванджалы  - слово белорусское.
Вот все что удалось найти:
КРЫНДЖАЛЫ Мсцісл., усх.-маг.; мсцісл. крыванджалы – вялікія сані на перавоз вялікіх бярвёнаў; літ. grįžulas, grįžulė, grįžalas ‘дышаль, паваротнае кола’.

т.е. возводится к литовскому слову, обозначающему ось (=поворотный круг?).

Comment: Говоря о том, что это название белорусское, вы навели меня на мысль о том, что в этом языке есть слово "крыж" - латинский крест, пришедшее в язык, вероятнее всего из польского во времена Речи Посполитой. Возможно, эти слова родственны.

Comment: >Возможно, эти слова родственны. 
  
Не думаю. С чего бы так измениться фонетике? "НДЖАЛ" это совсем не просто "Ж"

Comment: А в белорусском языке есть звуки /дж/ и /дз/. Например, в русском - "день рождения", а по-беларусску - "дзень нараджэння".

Comment: ДЗ точно есть.
Насчет ДЖ - не знаю, выделяется ли как самостоятельный звук.   
Посмотрел. Есть в белорусском Дж как самостоятельный звук.